# javascript function seems correct, yet

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am trying to solve the [Pokemon Damage Calculator](http://codewars.com/kata/536e9a7973130a06eb000e9f) kata, but I can not find the problem with my code

This is my code:

```js
function calculateDamage(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense) {
  let damage = 0;
  const effArr = [
    ["fire", "grass", 2],
    ["grass", "fire", 0.5],
    ["fire", "water", 0.5],
    ["water", "fire", 2],
    ["fire", "electric", 1],
    ["water", "grass", 0.5],
    ["grass", "water", 2],
    ["water", "electric", 0.5],
    ["electric", "water", 2]
    ["grass", "electric", 1]
  ];

  for (i = 0; damage == 0 && i < effArr.length; i++) {
    // console.log(effArr[i].indexOf(yourType) == 0, effArr[i].indexOf(opponentType) === 1, damage)
    if (effArr[i].indexOf(yourType) == 0 && effArr[i].indexOf(opponentType) == 1) {
      damage = (50 * effArr[i][2] * attack / defense)
    }
  }

  return damage;
}
```

This is the  expected result:

```js
calculateDamage("fire", "water", 100, 100)    => 25  
calculateDamage("grass", "water", 100, 100)   => 100
calculateDamage("electric", "fire", 100, 100) => 50
calculateDamage("grass", "electric", 57, 19)  => 150
```

but instead I get:

```js
calculateDamage("fire", "water", 100, 100)    => true false 0
calculateDamage("grass", "water", 100, 100)   => false false 0
calculateDamage("electric", "fire", 100, 100) => true true 0
calculateDamage("grass", "electric", 57, 19)  => false false 0
```

Comment: Well I don't know if it's *the* problem but the loop variable `i` should be declared.

Comment: Why don't you give the problem description, and a link to the codewars kata?

Comment: Looks like this one: https://www.codewars.com/kata/536e9a7973130a06eb000e9f

Comment: I mean, without that link, there is no question... it's "what's wrong with my code", and no further explanation, at all. edit: thanks Shiny, doing OP's work for him :)

Comment: If the program's requirements aren't specified, we can only tell you what it is doing.  To know what it *should* be doing, well, *you have to tell us*.

Comment: yes, this is the link.. regardless of the kata, I don't know what is wrong with my code

Comment: If there are no syntax errors in your code, it's impossible to tell any "error" in the code, without a description, on what it's supposed to do.

Comment: You haven't listed the intended behaviour, so no one can fix it, even if that were the purpose of stackoverflow. However, you're missing a comma in your effArr assignment. It's possible that if an issue can be fixed by using a standard feature of any IDE, that said issue doesn't belong here.

Comment: this is it:codewars.com/kata/536e9a7973130a06eb000e9f,  when I run it on Repl.it I get : ReferenceError: calculateDamage is not defined

Comment: @Ben, I am not sure where a comma is missing

Comment: Your type effectiveness array is incomplete as well, you should have 4 entries for each type (and they're not as the Pokemon game would have them, worryingly) - Though, as a tip, it's probably simpler to handle the types inside an Object

Comment: There should be a comma after `["electric", "water", 2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could approach this problem a little more effectively if you use an Object, rather than an Array - This way, you don't have to use a loop to search through your values, instead just using `yourType` and `opponentType` as [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to get the type effectiveness

Also, your original Array method was missing some type pairs, and I think you had missed the part of the kata description where it said *"any type against itself is not very effective"* - So I've amended this data slightly

```js
function calculateDamage(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense) {
  const matchups = {
    fire:     {fire: 0.5, water: 0.5, grass: 2.0, electric: 1.0},
    water:    {fire: 2.0, water: 0.5, grass: 0.5, electric: 0.5},
    grass:    {fire: 0.5, water: 2.0, grass: 0.5, electric: 1.0},
    electric: {fire: 1.0, water: 2.0, grass: 1.0, electric: 0.5}
  };

  let effectiveness = matchups[yourType][opponentType];

  return 50 * (attack / defense) * effectiveness;
}

console.log(`("fire", "water", 100, 100)     => ${calculateDamage("fire", "water", 100, 100)}`)
console.log(`("grass", "water", 100, 100)    => ${calculateDamage("grass", "water", 100, 100)}`)
console.log(`("electric", "fire", 100, 100)  => ${calculateDamage("electric", "fire", 100, 100)}`)
console.log(`("grass", "electric", 57, 19)   => ${calculateDamage("grass", "electric", 57, 19)}`)
```

---

If however you wanted your method to work, you'll need to fill in the missing entries for `electric`, and handle the missing `,` on the second to last entry of your Array.

Then, you'll just need to add a default `effectiveness` value to use when you have same type matchups; as these won't be caught in your current loop because [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) will return the *first* match found. For this fallback to work, matches in your for loop are now returned straight away, with the final return being the fallback with the default `effectiveness`

```js
function calculateDamage(yourType, opponentType, attack, defense) {
  let damage = 0;
  let effectiveness = 0.5; // Default value, used for same type matchups

  const effArr = [
    ["fire", "fire", 0.5],
    ["fire", "water", 0.5],
    ["fire", "grass", 2],
    ["fire", "electric", 1],

    ["water", "fire", 2],
    ["water", "water", 0.5],
    ["water", "grass", 0.5],
    ["water", "electric", 0.5],

    ["grass", "fire", 0.5],
    ["grass", "water", 2],
    ["grass", "grass", 0.5],
    ["grass", "electric", 1],

    ["electric", "fire", 1],
    ["electric", "water", 2],
    ["electric", "grass", 1],
    ["electric", "electric", 0.5]
  ];

  for (i = 0; damage == 0 && i < effArr.length; i++) {
    if (effArr[i].indexOf(yourType) == 0 && effArr[i].indexOf(opponentType) == 1) {
     return (50 * effArr[i][2] * attack / defense)
    }
  }

  return (50 * effectiveness  * attack / defense);
}

console.log(`("fire", "water", 100, 100)     => ${calculateDamage("fire", "water", 100, 100)}`)
console.log(`("grass", "water", 100, 100)    => ${calculateDamage("grass", "water", 100, 100)}`)
console.log(`("electric", "fire", 100, 100)  => ${calculateDamage("electric", "fire", 100, 100)}`)
console.log(`("grass", "electric", 57, 19)   => ${calculateDamage("grass", "electric", 57, 19)}`)
```